# Kubernetes Vulnerability Scanner

Tags: security, kubernetes

I am looking for options to integrate a vulnerability scanner with K8s. As a deployment is created, the scanner will scan the docker image/container and deliver results via json or yaml.
Is there any open source scanner out there?

Answer (score 1):

Some of the more popular open-source image scanners:

- [Trivy](https://github.com/aquasecurity/trivy)
- [Clair](https://github.com/quay/clair)
- [Anchore](https://github.com/anchore/anchore-engine)
- [Dagda](https://github.com/eliasgranderubio/dagda)

✌️